# Extending Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, inequality

Is it valid to extend Cauchy-Schwarz to the 3 variable case with the following proof:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n(a_ib_i) c_i \leq \sqrt{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2b_i^2)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i^2) } \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i^2}
$$

The first inequality simply applies Cauchy-Schwarz to the two variable case. The last inequality assumes $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2b_i^2\leq (\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2)$. Is this a valid assumption?

Comment: I doubt this is true. On the other hand, you have the triple scalar product inequality when $n=3$ and for higher dimensions you have determinant inequality. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319382/determinant-in-inner-product-space/2926630#2926630

Comment: My doubt was wrong. This question has been asked before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319382/determinant-in-inner-product-space/2926630#2926630

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and your proof works as you suggest. You can complete it by expanding the product $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2)(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2)$ and observing that the terms are all nonnegative and include all the terms of $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2b_i^2$.

Comment: ooooooh right!! thanks!!

Comment: is there a name for this inequality?

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: This inequality can be found in Michael Steele - The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class, Exercise 1.3 page 13.